# Could not find or load main class while executing jar file

Tags: java, jar

I have made jar file using netbeans, using Build and Clean Project Option.
And I got .jar file ,now when i Execute it for a short period of time cmd window appears and gives a error as "Could not find or load main class while executing jar file "

[image: Error That occured while executing]

But if I execute jar using command prompt java -jar `"C:\Users\varun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StockRegister\dist\StockRegister.jar"`
It works fine

Output of Netbeans is :

```
Updating property file: C:\Users\varun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StockRegister\build\built-clean.properties
Deleting directory C:\Users\varun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StockRegister\build
clean:
init:
deps-jar:
Created dir: C:\Users\varun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StockRegister\build
Updating property file: C:\Users\varun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StockRegister\build\built-jar.properties
Created dir: C:\Users\varun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StockRegister\build\classes
Created dir: C:\Users\varun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StockRegister\build\empty
Created dir: C:\Users\varun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StockRegister\build\generated-sources\ap-source-output
Compiling 8 source files to C:\Users\varun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StockRegister\build\classes
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
Note: C:\Users\varun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StockRegister\src\stockregister\EnterPurchase.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
Copying 17 files to C:\Users\varun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StockRegister\build\classes
compile:
Created dir: C:\Users\varun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StockRegister\dist
Copying 1 file to C:\Users\varun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StockRegister\build
Copy libraries to C:\Users\varun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StockRegister\dist\lib.
Building jar: C:\Users\varun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StockRegister\dist\StockRegister.jar
To run this application from the command line without Ant, try:
java -jar "C:\Users\varun\Documents\NetBeansProjects\StockRegister\dist\StockRegister.jar"
```

And in jar file ,I renamed it to .zip and opened it ,in Meta-Inf Folder of jar 
Manifest.MF says :

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Ant-Version: Apache Ant 1.8.4
Created-By: 1.7.0_25-b16 (Oracle Corporation)
Class-Path: lib/AbsoluteLayout.jar lib/mysql-connector-java-5.0.8-bin.
 jar lib/swingx-all-1.6.4.jar
X-COMMENT: Main-Class will be added automatically by build
Main-Class: stockregister.StockRegister
```

Does any one has any idea why this is happening.

Answer (score 1):

You might have defined more than one class with **main** method.
Use **only 1 class with main method**.
Which would be your launcher class.(Will run first of all).

Comment: You can have many classes, each having a main method. You specify which one to start with using `Main-Class: MyPackage.MyClass` in `manifest.mf`

Comment: @Marichyasana I have specified My main class, if I run through Jar by double clicking on it ,gives error while using cmd : java -jar pathtojar it works fine ,thats the issue i am facing

Comment: @Danish I have configured launching class via Manifest , and if that would   be the case than , it won't run through calling jar file using cmd.